# Inner join function duplicates content

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

My query duplicates the entries I get. I use two Inner join. The strange fact is that I made this code 6 months ago and, as far as I remember, it worked. Now, I come back to my project and it does not work anymore (it duplicates)...

**The Query :**

```
$sql_principale_news = "SELECT sys_pre_values.LKey,bx_blogs_posts.PostUri,bx_blogs_posts.PostCaption,bx_blogs_posts.PostText,bx_blogs_posts.PostText,bx_blogs_posts.Categories,
      bx_blogs_posts.PostDate,bx_blogs_posts.Views,bx_blogs_posts.CommentsCount,bx_blogs_posts.allowView,Profiles.Avatar,Profiles.ID,Profiles.FirstName,Profiles.LastName,Profiles.ProfileType
      FROM bx_blogs_posts
      INNER JOIN Profiles ON bx_blogs_posts.OwnerID=Profiles.ID AND Profiles.Status='Active'
      INNER JOIN sys_pre_values ON bx_blogs_posts.NewsType=sys_pre_values.Value AND sys_pre_values.Value!=sys_pre_values.LKey
      WHERE bx_blogs_posts.OpenNews=1 
        AND bx_blogs_posts.PostStatus='approval'
        AND bx_blogs_posts.Categories IN ('".$innov24_config."')
        AND (bx_blogs_posts.allowView=3 
          OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView=4 
          OR (bx_blogs_posts.allowView=5 AND bx_blogs_posts.OwnerID IN ('".$bigfriendlist."')) 
          OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView IN ('".$privacy_OthersToMe."') 
          OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView IN ('".$privacy_MeToOthers."'))
      ORDER BY bx_blogs_posts.PostDate DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['debut'].",".$nb_affichage_par_page."";
```

**The résult :**

It duplicates each entry 3 times.

[image: The same entry appears 3 times each]

**The problem**

If I delete the second inner join, there is no more duplicate.

```
$sql_principale_news = "SELECT sys_pre_values.LKey,bx_blogs_posts.PostUri,bx_blogs_posts.PostCaption,bx_blogs_posts.PostText,bx_blogs_posts.PostText,bx_blogs_posts.Categories,
      bx_blogs_posts.PostDate,bx_blogs_posts.Views,bx_blogs_posts.CommentsCount,bx_blogs_posts.allowView,Profiles.Avatar,Profiles.ID,Profiles.FirstName,Profiles.LastName,Profiles.ProfileType
      FROM bx_blogs_posts
      INNER JOIN Profiles ON bx_blogs_posts.OwnerID=Profiles.ID AND Profiles.Status='Active'
      // DELETED CODE // INNER JOIN sys_pre_values ON bx_blogs_posts.NewsType=sys_pre_values.Value AND sys_pre_values.Value!=sys_pre_values.LKey// END DELETED CODE //
      WHERE bx_blogs_posts.OpenNews=1 
        AND bx_blogs_posts.PostStatus='approval'
        AND bx_blogs_posts.Categories IN ('".$innov24_config."')
        AND (bx_blogs_posts.allowView=3 
          OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView=4 
          OR (bx_blogs_posts.allowView=5 AND bx_blogs_posts.OwnerID IN ('".$bigfriendlist."')) 
          OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView IN ('".$privacy_OthersToMe."') 
          OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView IN ('".$privacy_MeToOthers."'))
      ORDER BY bx_blogs_posts.PostDate DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['debut'].",".$nb_affichage_par_page."";
```

Does anyone could say why?

[EDIT] Here are the Tables structures

[image: sys_pre_values]

[image: Profiles 1/3]

[image: Profiles 2/3]

[image: Profiles 3/3]

[image: bx_blogs_posts]

Comment: Provide your table structure

Comment: If you execute `select * from sys_pre_values where Value != LKey`, do you get three records?

Comment: yes @Xint0 I do have 3 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use GROUP BY

try this

```
   $sql_principale_news = "SELECT sys_pre_values.LKey,bx_blogs_posts.PostUri,bx_blogs_posts.PostCaption,bx_blogs_posts.PostText,bx_blogs_posts.PostText,bx_blogs_posts.Categories,
  bx_blogs_posts.PostDate,bx_blogs_posts.Views,bx_blogs_posts.CommentsCount,bx_blogs_posts.allowView,Profiles.Avatar,Profiles.ID,Profiles.FirstName,Profiles.LastName,Profiles.ProfileType
  FROM bx_blogs_posts
  INNER JOIN Profiles ON bx_blogs_posts.OwnerID=Profiles.ID AND Profiles.Status='Active'
   INNER JOIN sys_pre_values ON bx_blogs_posts.NewsType=sys_pre_values.Value AND sys_pre_values.Value!=sys_pre_values.LKey// END DELETED CODE //
  WHERE bx_blogs_posts.OpenNews=1 
    AND bx_blogs_posts.PostStatus='approval'
    AND bx_blogs_posts.Categories IN ('".$innov24_config."')
    AND (bx_blogs_posts.allowView=3 
      OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView=4 
      OR (bx_blogs_posts.allowView=5 AND bx_blogs_posts.OwnerID IN ('".$bigfriendlist."')) 
      OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView IN ('".$privacy_OthersToMe."') 
      OR bx_blogs_posts.allowView IN ('".$privacy_MeToOthers."'))
 GROUP BY sys_pre_values.LKey
  ORDER BY bx_blogs_posts.PostDate DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['debut'].",".$nb_affichage_par_page."";
```

Comment: It might be something like "GROUP BY bx_blogs_posts.OwnerID" (still need more testing) but Group By is the solution. Thank you!